# Oozie workflow schema error

Tags: xml, hadoop, oozie, hue

I am working on a project using Hue/Oozie to create work flows. The problem I am having is that multiple times now I have had a workflow working then made an edit which has resulted in an throwing the error:

> OozieClientException: org.apache.oozie.DagEngineException: E0701: XML schema error, cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'action'. One of '{WC["uri:oozie:sla:0.1","uri:oozie:sla:0.2"]}' is expected.

or something similar. This has resulted in me having to completely recreate the workflow at which point it works fine. If I look at the workflow.xml file then some of the actions are in the incorrect order even though they are fine in the oozie gui. I could edit the workflow to fix the issue but afaik its not possible to edit the workflow through changing the xml. I have no idea what is causing this.

Comment: *Hue* is causing this. Anything more complex than "Hello World" requires an XML editor, plus a Linux shell with Oozie command-line tool.

Comment: Sorry, do you mind clarifying this? Are you saying that the correct method is dumping Hue and using pure XML/terminal for Oozie?

Comment: I don't how the Yahoo! ops team (which designed & maintain Oozie) manage their workflows -- maybe they've got a dedicated IDE. For the rest of us, I see no better alternative, sorry...

Comment: In case you want to see some realistic examples of Coordinator / Workflow XML definitions, you will find a good tutorial in that series of blog posts >> http://hadooped.blogspot.fr/2013/10/apache-oozie-part-13-oozie-ssh-action_30.html *(it's a bit old, but Oozie has not changed that much in 3 years, except for supporting for Spark and some Kerberos `credentials`)*

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same problem. It turns out the `</action>` was wrote to `<action/>` by mistabke.

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify whether all corresponding end tags are properly given. There could be chance of missing giving </ action>  end tag